# Convert Azimuth/Elevation of a celestial body to Longitude/Latitude on geographic map

Tags: python, dictionary, path, elevation, azimuth

I'm working on a project related to astronomy and orbital mechanics.
I have some data for a celestial body(for example a satellite or moon...) like it's Azimuth/Elevation, sidereal time of observation, longitude and latitude of observation site...
I can calculate Right ascension and declination of the target by using above information.
Well, We have for example 200 observation of the celestial body sorted by time (t1,t2,...tn)
How can I change these information to Longitude/Latitude of the celestial body in geographic map for each time?
I want to create a map like this:

[image: path]
<sub>(source: [qsl.net](http://www.qsl.net/kd2bd/map_program.gif))</sub>

*** I use python in my project.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math. Maybe you should move it to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can't. I've flagged it, a moderator will have to move it..

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example here http://www.stargazing.net/kepler/altaz.html You are working backwards from RA and DEC and you should get Long from the LST and LAT from setting ALT to 90 and rearrange.

Comment: actually I can calculate Longitude by using LST and Hour Angle. But Altitude is a little involute. Can you explain it?

Comment: The spear of stars in RA and DEC rotate around the north pole. So at a latitude of 90 degrees at the north pole you have the pole star at DEC 90 above you. At a latitude of 30 degrees stars at DEC 30 will transit the zenith. Therefore it is just:

Dec. of zenith = observer's latitude (and because you are calculating when the satellite is at the zenith you already have the latitude I think)